# Error LessError: Cannot find module '@/utils/utils.less'

Tags: reactjs

here is my package.json file. I get Error LessError: Cannot find module '@/utils/utils.less' today, but it was workking fine few days ago.

Comment: Have you tried running `npm install` or `yarn`? (depending on which you're using.

Comment: I tried npm install so many times but it does't work. is there any package  need to be installed ?

Comment: It also shows this error
 type: 'Syntax',
  filename: 'C:\\react\\procheck-web\\src\\pages\\AverageDashboard\\Index.less',
  index: 128,
  line: 3,
  column: 0,
  callLine: NaN,
  callExtract: undefined,
  extract: [
    "@import '~antd/lib/style/themes/default.less';",
    "@import '~@/utils/utils.less';",
    ''
  ]
}

Comment: What does your AverageDashboard code look like? Seems the error is in there.

Comment: You said 'Here is my package.json file' buth there is not JSON at all in your post. Maybe you forgot to copy it.

Comment: issues resolve i just use ' instead of ' thanks

Comment: Those two characters are identical :-/